# ASP.NET handle sub-domains using routhing

Tags: asp.net, routes, subdomain

How can I route sub-domains to asp.net application pages?

http://test1.domain.com  ===>   http://www.domain.com/id=test1

Answer (score 0):

I think what you did there was an URL rewritting in IIS :
http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite